# Is the usage of 'Due to urgent personal errands' valid?

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage

I see in my company mails, there is a lot of usage of the statement *Due to urgent personal errands* (..I may not report to office today) which, by hunch, I guess is not a proper usage.

What is the correct way to use it,if I am right?

Comment: It looks fairly standard to my eyes, but perhaps I'm missing something. Why do you have a hunch it is not correct?  What seems incorrect about it?

Comment: May be usage of _Due to_ with _Errands_ is not correct?

Comment: It needs a verb to make it a grammatical sentence. I am just trying to think what that verb should be. One doesn't *make* an errand, one usually *runs* an errand - for someone else. So perhaps *Due to having to run some/undertake some urgent personal errands...*. But it seems a very unspecific explanation for suddenly taking time off work, I must say.

Comment: "Due to" is usually followed by a noun in my experience, as in "Due to the blizzard, school is closed today" or "Due to his high fever, Jason stayed in bed".  "Due to urgent personal errands" is a correct formulation as an opening clause (of the complete sentence you show later), but it also implies that the errands were unavoidable.

Comment: Are you referring to the old dispute about using "Due to..." as a prepositional phrase? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20to

Comment: @WS2, **Since** _having to run some/undertake some urgent personal errands_, may be?

Comment: @MarkThompson I have followed it by a noun - *having to run* (a gerund phrase). When I said it needed a verb, that was not strictly correct.

Comment: @Sree You conclude with a question mark, but I am puzzled as to what you are asking.

Comment: Sree: No, _since_ cannot be used with a gerund in this sense. It requires a clause as its object when it means _because_. @WS2 I actually find the sentence a lot neater and less cumbersome with no gerund. “Due to having to run some urgent personal errands” is unnecessarily wordy and (IMO) clumsy compared to “Due to urgent personal errands”.

Comment: This is stretching the meaning of _due to_, however: your urgent personal errands are only quite indirectly the cause of your not coming in to the office. There's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence, but it is a bit awkward. A more natural way of phrasing it might be “I have some urgent personal matters to attend to, and may not be able to make it to the office today”, _vel sim_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But if you just say *due to...errands*, it doesn't clarify anything about the *errands*. But I suppose we say *Due to snow, I shall not be there*. So you may well be right. I, perhaps, couldn't get over the fact that someone was offering such an abbreviated reason for not coming in to work. It sounded a bit like *Due to some inconvenience I shall not be at work today*. You wouldn't have got away with that in my time. But then I suppose the workplace isn't what it once was.

Comment: Why are we debating grammar rather than pointing out that *errands* cannot be *urgent*, and trying to describe them as such renders this not only a lame excuse (as Scott so aptly put it), but an *obvious* one as well?

Answer (score 1):

> *Due to urgent personal errands, I may not report to the office today.*

This is a lame excuse, and it might have gotten a person fired ten years ago, but it seems there is no problem with the grammar.

***Due to*** is used prepositionally, validated by [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/due?q=due%20to#due_to) under *due*:

> The use of *due to* as a prepositional phrase meaning ‘*because of*’ (as
>   in he had to retire due to an injury) first appeared in print in 1897,
>   and traditional grammarians have opposed this prepositional usage for
>   more than a century on the grounds that it is a misuse of the
>   adjectival phrase *due to* in the sense of ‘attributable to, likely or
>   expected to’ ( the train is due to arrive at 11:15), or ‘payable or
>   owed to’ ( render unto Caesar what is due to Caesar). Nevertheless,
>   this prepositional usage is now **widespread and common** in all types of
>   literature and must be regarded as standard English. The phrase *due to*
>   the fact that is very common in speech, but it is wordy, and,
>   especially in writing, one should use instead the simple word *because*.

***Errands*** is the object of the preposition, and the adjectives ***urgent*** and ***personal*** modify *errands*, to complete the leading prepositional phrase:

> *Due to urgent personal errands,*

***I*** is the subject of the sentence (apparently the person with the urgent personal errands).

***May*** is the auxiliary of the verb ***report***, negated by ***not***, and modified temporally by ***today***.

***To the office*** is a prepositional phrase modifying ***report*** locationally, and completing the meaningful sentence:

> *Due to urgent personal errands, I may not report to the office today.*